# Performing function on user permissions granting result?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, closures

I ask the user if they will allow notifications, I then want to animate a tick if they approve. Im unsure how to achieve this as permissions are async and i cant then detect a result instantly to perform a func?

Here is my current code:

user taps button and triggers a call to grant permissions with a closure to tick the button on completion

```
func userDidTapNotifications() {
    self.appDelegate.setupNotifications { (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            notificationsGranted()
        }
    }
}
```

function presents the approval pop up and completes closure, issue is that it will complete before the user has picked a choice as its async, so im completing true before the user has granted access, causing issues.

```
func setupNotifications(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }
    completion(true)
}
```

after this I call my final func on completion of closure:

```
func notificationsGranted() {
    let isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications = UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
    if isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
        self.permissionsView.notificationsSwitch.setSelected(true, animated: true)
        self.userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "notificationsApproved")
        arePermissionsGranted()
    }
}
```

What would be the correct approach to present the permissions alert, then take action based on a response?

Comment: What you are doing now will show animation once user allows the app to access notification which is what u wanted correct ? RegisterForRemoteNotification is a async call and all it does is gets a device token from APNS and should update your server with token which user should never be bothered about, So what you are doing is fine

Comment: the issue is that its not animating, its failing becuse im checking if a permission is approved before I do anything, and at the point its called the user hasnt yet selected to approve, they are viewing the approval box options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store you completion handler in a global object in your `AppDelegate` and when `didRegisterRemoteNotification` method is invoke then just invoke the completion handler that you have stored...
And in your `ViewController` you should call `setUpNotification` method.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var notificationCompletion: ((Bool)->Void)?



    func setUpNotification(completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void) {
        self.notificationCompletion = completion //Store the completion in a global property to use later.

        //Invoke Your Notification Registration methods...
        //Do not invoke the completion handle here...
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        //Permission is granted. Now invoke the completion that you have store to use later.
        if let completion = self.notificationCompletion {
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        //Permission is not granted/failed. Now invoke the completion that you have store to use later.
        if let completion = self.notificationCompletion {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}


ViewController.swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.setUpNotification(completion: { isPermissionGranted in
                if isPermissionGranted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.notificationPermissionIsGranted()
                    }
                }

            })
        }
    }
    func notificationPermissionIsGranted() {
        //Animate Your View..
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: this code didnt work for me unfortunately, it opens the approval box but never calls the animate func

Comment: I have tested it and then answered it. You may have skip something thats why.

Comment: Can you show me the code that you have write after implementing using my above answer.?

Comment: i got it working, issue is on simulator there is no device token so it wouldnt call the func, it needs to be ran on a device

Comment: is there a similar way to achieve this same series of actions with location manager? as theres no token assign delegate

Comment: What do you mean can you explain it little more what you want to with locationManager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159221/discussion-between-jackdm-and-syed-qamar-abbas).